# Drawing mechanics in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Does anyone have any ideas on how to implement drawing mechanic like in games such as Draw Climber or Scribble rider?
If anyone has something please share because I'm stumped
I read a lot of information about LINE RENDERER and PROCEDURAL MESH GENERATION, but I can't figure out how to connect it all

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BuBEsvfrsI - Draw Climber

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5-__p5OMzw - Scribble Rider

Comment: You would be better to ask these sorts of questions over at [Unity](https://answers.unity.com/index.html).   Good luck!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a [`LineRenderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) with an [`EdgeCollider2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-EdgeCollider2D.html) and add some positions to it. [Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmBQQ2XtuhU&t=1054s) has a good tutorial on that.